# Worklight 6.1 - Adapter failed to response maximum times

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using worklight 6.1 and build a project which is hitting http adapter and getting response in xml format. The problem is whenever we are hitting the adapter maximum times it is giving error saying `The service is currently not available`. Error logs which we are getting in console is given below

```
05-08 16:16:57.787: E/NONE(23389): [http://domain/appname/apps/services/api/appname/android/query] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
05-08 16:16:57.817: D/NONE(23389): {
05-08 16:16:57.817: D/NONE(23389):     "invocationContext": null,
05-08 16:16:57.817: D/NONE(23389):     "errorCode": "UNRESPONSIVE_HOST",
05-08 16:16:57.817: D/NONE(23389):     "errorMsg": "The service is currently not available."
05-08 16:16:57.817: D/NONE(23389): }
```

This is really a critical issue. 
In my case we have put timeout as 5 minute everywhere on adapter side and when invoking adapter procedure even on server but in case of error it is not even hitting the adapter i think. Please let me know what is the exact issue and what should we configure.

Answer (score 0):

Set the maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode in your adapter to handle the concurrent connections.